# Why doesn't `grep -v` invert the matching?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to search for a certain url across many repos via `ag -l --hidden <url>`, but a large number of the results look like `ERR: Error opening directory ./Library/Containers/com.apple.news: Operation not permitted`. I want to exclude these.

So I was running `ag -l --hidden <url> | grep -v Error` but then all it does is ONLY match those lines, and excludes everything else! It's like it's ignoring the `-v` flag for inversion.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The error messages are likely on `stderr` and not filtered by your `grep`. You probably need `2>&1` after your `ag` command.

Comment: Oh no doubt you're right, thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: Yep, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote Mark Setchell's comment above:

> The error messages are likely on stderr and not filtered by your grep. You probably need 2>&1 after your ag command.

That is to say, while the normal output of `ag` is to stdout, which is what's piped to grep, the error messages are going to stderr, which is not piped.

By using `2>&1`, stderr for the `ag` command is redirected to stdout, so grep filters it as well.